# Could not cast value of type _NCSFDictionary to NSArray Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

In my code I am doing a guard statement so I can loop through JSON and get the data I want but I keep getting an error saying "Could not cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary' to 'NSArray'." Here is my code:

```
urlSession.dataTaskWithURL(urlWithJSON, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
     do {
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! NSDictionary
        guard let query:[AnyObject] = json["query"] as! [AnyObject] else {
             throw StockError.InvalidArray
         }
```

I am force downcasting to an NSDictionary because I need to get keys of specific items in the JSON data, when trying to force downcast to NSArray I get an error about it expecting an int.

Edit: Here is JavaScript code used to get the JSON data:
var sync = require("sync-request");

```
var urlBeginning = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22";
var urlEnding = "%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=";

var getStockValue = function(symbol) {
    var url = urlBeginning + symbol + urlEnding;
    var res = sync('GET', url);
    var data = JSON.parse(res.getBody().toString('utf8'));
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.query.results);
};

getStockValue("GOOG");
```

Which outputs:

```
{ query: 
   { count: 1,
     created: '2015-11-24T10:13:49Z',
     lang: 'en-US',
     diagnostics: 
      { url: [Object],
        publiclyCallable: 'true',
        cache: [Object],
        query: [Object],
        javascript: [Object],
        'user-time': '30',
        'service-time': '10',
        'build-version': '0.2.311' },
     results: { quote: [Object] } } }
{ quote: 
   { symbol: 'GOOG',
     Ask: '754.13',
     AverageDailyVolume: '2244760',
     Bid: '749.49',
     AskRealtime: null,
     BidRealtime: null,
     BookValue: '169.03',
     Change_PercentChange: '-0.62 - -0.08%',
     Change: '-0.62',
     Commission: null,
     Currency: 'USD',
     ChangeRealtime: null,
     AfterHoursChangeRealtime: null,
     DividendShare: null,
     LastTradeDate: '11/23/2015',
     TradeDate: null,
     EarningsShare: '23.72',
     ErrorIndicationreturnedforsymbolchangedinvalid: null,
     EPSEstimateCurrentYear: '28.99',
     EPSEstimateNextYear: '34.22',
     EPSEstimateNextQuarter: '7.80',
     DaysLow: '751.82',
     DaysHigh: '762.71',
     YearLow: '486.23',
     YearHigh: '762.71',
     HoldingsGainPercent: null,
     AnnualizedGain: null,
     HoldingsGain: null,
     HoldingsGainPercentRealtime: null,
     HoldingsGainRealtime: null,
     MoreInfo: null,
     OrderBookRealtime: null,
     MarketCapitalization: '519.91B',
     MarketCapRealtime: null,
     EBITDA: '23.30B',
     ChangeFromYearLow: '269.75',
     PercentChangeFromYearLow: '+55.48%',
     LastTradeRealtimeWithTime: null,
     ChangePercentRealtime: null,
     ChangeFromYearHigh: '-6.73',
     PercebtChangeFromYearHigh: '-0.88%',
     LastTradeWithTime: '4:00pm - <b>755.98</b>',
     LastTradePriceOnly: '755.98',
     HighLimit: null,
     LowLimit: null,
     DaysRange: '751.82 - 762.71',
     DaysRangeRealtime: null,
     FiftydayMovingAverage: '696.65',
     TwoHundreddayMovingAverage: '614.49',
     ChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage: '141.49',
     PercentChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage: '+23.03%',
     ChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage: '59.33',
     PercentChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage: '+8.52%',
     Name: 'Alphabet Inc.',
     Notes: null,
     Open: '757.45',
     PreviousClose: '756.60',
     PricePaid: null,
     ChangeinPercent: '-0.08%',
     PriceSales: '7.25',
     PriceBook: '4.48',
     ExDividendDate: null,
     PERatio: '31.87',
     DividendPayDate: null,
     PERatioRealtime: null,
     PEGRatio: '1.48',
     PriceEPSEstimateCurrentYear: '26.08',
     PriceEPSEstimateNextYear: '22.09',
     Symbol: 'GOOG',
     SharesOwned: null,
     ShortRatio: '1.81',
     LastTradeTime: '4:00pm',
     TickerTrend: null,
     OneyrTargetPrice: '853.67',
     Volume: '1415536',
     HoldingsValue: null,
     HoldingsValueRealtime: null,
     YearRange: '486.23 - 762.71',
     DaysValueChange: null,
     DaysValueChangeRealtime: null,
     StockExchange: 'NMS',
     DividendYield: null,
     PercentChange: '-0.08%' } }
```

Comment: could you provide the json data? It seems like the thing you're trying to cast into an array is a JSON Object rather than an array.

Comment: @JanGreve Sure, https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22goog%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback= That's the url for Alphabet''s share value, in my code I use \(ticker) where goog can be found so I can have user input when getting the data.

Comment: That does not work to curl for me. Could you just log the data you're actually parsing as a UTF8 string and edit your question accordingly?

Comment: I've added it in the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay. So, you're accessing `query` from that JSON, which is a JSON Object. Those get mapped to NSDictionaries, so a cast to `[AnyObject]` is bound to fail.

Cast it to `NSDictionary` and you will be fine.